# Execute jQuery after other scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to change some styling on my page. The page is made dynamically by executing another JavaScript file.

Right now I have

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('p').css('font','green');
});
```

Which does nothing.

`$(document).ready(function()` will change the static part of the page, but not the generated part.

If I just type `$('p').css('font','green');` in the console, the expected results will happen. What is going on?

Comment: Shouldn't `$('p').css('font','green');` be `$('p').css('color','green');`?

Comment: Is this external script doing anything to the page after it has been executed?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you are asking to be able to bind events to objects?

If so, look up the jQuery live() function:  http://api.jquery.com/live/

If you are simply trying to apply CSS Styles to the page, you're better off relying on actual CSS style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for the `document` ready event, can you listen to an event fired by a `workcomplete` script building the page?

Or can you test for something in the page to indicate it's done every 100ms and then fire such an event yourself?